# Resize UICollectionView section header causes overlap with below header when all items in section are deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a section header UIView with a UILabel subview. Selecting items in this section populates the header's UILabel with text and the label wraps to more lines as the text gets longer.

I'm using

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to return a new header size when the UILabel height grows. This works well. The height of label grows and so does the height of section header.

All items can be deleted in the section with the following

```
[self performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:nil];
```

The problem is that the animation upward of the below section header does not accommodate the new height of header. The below section header is positioned to where it would be if the header's height did not increase. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the cells, try to increase the bottom of the section's inset of the same section by the same amount as you increased the header.